# remove the URL string and leave just the domain using regex in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to remove the URL's in a domain using RegEx. Example URL's below. however when I want to remove the URL on the 3rd example below. It doesn't work.

```
http://www.domain.com.org
https://www.domain.com.org
http://domain.com.org
```

My first IF condition works fine if the URL is say http://www.domain.com.org . I use a split() to separate the whole URL by dot. 
However if my URL is w/o the www (http://domain.com.org) it doesn't work. In my FOR loop I would would compare the current value of x to my regex2 result if they match I would remove() it by creating another regex to strip down the URL and leave the domain and have it added in my var(word)

I know there are other way to do this, however based on my skill level on both python and regex this is how I would approach it. Is my code really feasible or I am doing an impossible thing and my code needs redoing?

I'm  pretty new in Python and I just learned RegEx a couple of days ago. However I know my regex is good based on my test. I believe my code flow is really screwed up. Any idea folks?

```
import re
def domain_name2(url):

word = url.split('.')
print(word)

#regex1 = '\w+\W+www.'
regex2 = '\w+\W+\w+'
result2 = re.search(regex2, url).group()
print(result2)

for x in word:

    #if x in re.search(regex1, url).group():
    #    word.remove(x)
    if x in result2: 
        word.remove(re.search('\w+\W+',x).group())
return word


['http://domain', 'com', 'org']
http://domain
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-324-e34a89862aeb> in <module>
----> 1 domain_name2('http://domain.com.org')

<ipython-input-319-877bb80b77f0> in domain_name2(url)
 18         #    word.remove(x)
 19         if x in result2:
 ---> 20             word.remove(re.search('\w+\W+',x).group())
 21     return word
 22 

 ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but you can parse the URL to get the so called netloc part.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
result = urlparse(url).netloc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for the if statement as well.

```
import re 

string = "https://domain.com.org"

def url_slice(string):
    if 'www' in string:
        res = re.search('(?<=\.).+', string)
    else:
        res = re.search('(?<=\/\/).+', string)
    return res.group()

print(url_slice(string)) #domain.com.org
```

Comment: actually the result i want to have is to remove www so that only the domain and TLD is left in the result.  From: http://example.org TO: example.org ; FROM:http://www.example.org TO example.org

Comment: been busy for a while, can you explain to me the regex used>? i can see that you put it in a group  (?<=\.).+  and ?<=\/\/).+  hope you can give me the interpretation of that..all i know from there is the ?